# Quarkus: Inject/Use CDI bean inside a non-CDI bean

Tags: singleton, quarkus, cdi, inject

I'm trying to inject my singleton bean into a non-bean class, but for now, I always get that my injected dependency is null.

Quarkus: 3.2.2

```
@Named("singletonConfiguration")
@Singleton
public class Configuration {

    private static Configuration INSTANCE = null;

        private Configuration() {
    }

    public static synchronized Configuration getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Configuration();
                }

        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

```
@Named("producerConfiguration")
@Singleton
public class ConfigurationProducer {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public Configuration produceConfiguration() {
        return Configuration.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I tried 2 different implementation, both of them dont work

```
public class Test {

        @Inject
    @Named("producerConfiguration")
    private ConfigurationProducer configurationProducer;

    public Test() {
    }

    public void doIt() {
        Configuration configuration = configurationProducer.produceConfiguration();
        System.out.println("TEST");
                // throw err *... because "this.configurationProducer" is null*
        System.out.println(configuration); 

    }

}
```

or

```
public class Test {

    @Inject
    @Named("producerConfiguration")
    Configuration configuration;

    public Test() {
    }

    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        System.out.println(configuration); // -> print 'null'
    }
}
```

But if I use Configuration Singleton bean inside another bean, everything works

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationService {

    @Inject
    @Named("singletonConfiguration")
    Configuration config;


        .... (config is NOT null here)

}
```

PS if it will help, I can make Configuration class @ApplicationScoped insted of @Singleton

Comment: Indeed, injection to instances that are not managed by the DI framework (be it CDI, Spring, whatever) does not work. There are ways around it, but the first question is **why do you want to manage your `Test` bean yourself and not let CDI handle it?**

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos The main point is to be able to create a new instance of the Test class using the 'new' keyword. If there is a way to achieve this and have Test as part of CDI, that's fine. I just haven't found how to do it

Comment: Injection into non-bean classes will never work. You can lookup the instance programmatically (using `CDI.current()` or `Arc.container()`), but you should first think about how you structure the application -- fighting against the DI container extensively will likely bring a lot of pain. Doing it on a very few selected places should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected; CDI will only inject into instances of beans it manages - non-CDI classes won't work.
If you want to fully leverage CDI, you should mostly stick to that and avoid injecting into non-CDI classes.
However, that's not always possible and you can use programmatic lookup to do just that - the CDI way is via `CDI.current.select(...).get()` but in Quarkus I'd recommend `Arc.container()` to achieve the same.

> The main point is to be able to create a new instance of the Test class using the 'new' keyword. If there is a way to achieve this and have Test as part of CDI, that's fine. I just haven't found how to do it

That depends on how is the test class created (is the no-args constructor or one that has only injectable dependencies?) and if you need to create the class instance before or after CDI container already runs. If you could turn the `Test` class into a CDI bean, you could then just ask the container for an instance of that bean via programmatic lookup.